# Isnull still return null value

Tags: sql

So I'm trying to select field 1 from table 2 that has been left outer joinned to table 1, and i want to return field1 as blank instead of null with the isnull() command. but it's still returning null value for me. Here's the query I have:

```
select 
  field1 
from 
  table1 
  left outer join (select
                    (isNull(field1,''))field1, 
                    id2 
                   from table2)tb2 on table1.id1= tb2.id2
```

Anyone know where the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using as the `LEFT` table the `table1`.

If `table1` contains an `id1` that does not match `id2` from the `table2` then there is nothing returned from the `table2` and so the conversion does not occur.

You will have to use the `isNull` on the first part of the select.

```
SELECT 
  isnull(field1,'') 
FROM table1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
     SELECT field1, id2 FROM table2
  ) tb2 ON table1.id1= tb2.id2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `COALESCE()` instead of `ISNULL()`

Comment: neither worked, i tried coalesce(field1, '') and it still returned null, ifnull is not a recognized command in mssql

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the derived query, just do a normal join:

```
select coalesce(field1,'') as field1 
from   table1 
left outer join table2
on table1.id1= tb2.id2
```

And if you were using the `COALESCE` in your original query, that would not have worked; it would be needed on the main `SELECT` statement.